# Iterate over a collection and put results in a Variable?

Tags: jstl

I tried asking this question but may have worded it wrong.  Im doing this:

```
<c:forEach var="cell" items="${row}" varStatus="rowStatus">
    <td class="data_extract">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${results.types[rowStatus.index].array}">
                <c:forEach var="elem" items="${cell}" varStatus="cellStatus">
                    ${elem}<c:if test="${!cellStatus.last}">,&nbsp;</c:if>
                </c:forEach>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                ${cell}
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </td>
```

For example `${elem}` will loop a couple times and will have this in the cell:  "10GT,  137S" after the loop is done.  I want to maybe concatenante a variable so "10GT,  137S" is assigned a variable so that I might pass into:

`<span class="mouseover_text" title="${NEW VARIABLE HERE!!!!!!!}"></span>`

Please help a brother...

EDIT:
This seems to work!!

```
<td class="data_extract">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${results.types[rowStatus.index].array}">
            <c:set var="comma" value="," />
            <c:forEach var="elem" items="${cell}" varStatus="cellStatus">
                <c:set var="myVar" value="${cellStatus.first ? '' : myVar} ${elem} ${cellStatus.last ? '' : comma}" /> 
            </c:forEach>
            <span class="mouseover_text" title="${myVar}">${myVar}</span>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            ${cell}
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td class="data_extract">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${results.types[rowStatus.index].array}">
            <c:set var="comma" value="," />
            <c:forEach var="elem" items="${cell}" varStatus="cellStatus">
                <c:set var="myVar" value="${cellStatus.first ? '' : myVar} ${elem} ${cellStatus.last ? '' : comma}" /> 
            </c:forEach>
            <span class="mouseover_text" title="${myVar}">${myVar}</span>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            ${cell}
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</td>
```